Pointwise limit of sequence of holomorphic functions given constraint on their derivatives at the origin
Consider a sequence of functions $g_n(z)$. $n$ takes values on the natural numbers, and $z$ is a complex variable. For all $n$, $g_n(z)$ is guaranteed to be an analytic function of $z$ within a disk of radius $R \geq 1$ centered at the origin.
Suppose I know that for all $n$ and $m$, $\left|\frac{1}{m!}\left(\frac{d}{dz}\right)^m g(n,z)|_{z=0}\right| \leq 1$.
I also know that for each $z$ in the unit disk, $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(z) = f(z)$, converging pointwise.
Then am I guaranteed that the pointwise limit $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function within a disk surrounding the origin?

I study physics, and my analysis background is weak. I'm trying to better understand what it means for statistical mechanical models to undergo phase transitions in terms of their analyticity properties. The above is a toy problem to help me understand when I'm guaranteed that the limit of a function is analytic.
From searching on MSE, I found a question mentioning Osgood's theorem, which I interpret as saying that the pointwise limit of holomorphic functions in an open region $O$ is itself guaranteed to be holomorphic in a smaller open region $D \subset O$. However, $D$'s "center" doesn't have to be the center of the original disk $O$, as I see in Example 1 in these lecture notes.
However, I'm hopeful that the $\left|\frac{1}{m!}\left(\frac{d}{dz}\right)^m g_n(z)|_{z=0}\right| \leq 1$ constraint might rule out such examples.

I realized that Vitali's convergence theorem should probably work. Here's a sketch: the analyticity of $g_n(z)$ and the bounds on their derivatives in turn uniformly bound the functions $g_n(z)$ within any disk of radius $r$<1. Then noting that the pointwise convergence is guaranteed within the unit disk, all of Vitali's hypotheses are confirmed for any disk of radius $r$<1, and so $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function on any disk of radius $r$<1. (All disks are centered at the origin).

I'll write this as an answer in the next few days but I won't mind if someone else writes it first.
